# Is there a way to examine the contents of a SAP HANADB transaction log

Tags: hana

I have a SAP B1 system that's being migrated from Microsoft SQL to HANA DB. Our solution in the staging environment is producing huge transaction logs, tens of gigabytes in an hour, but the system isn't receiving production workloads yet. SAP have indicated that the database is fine, and that it's our software that's at fault, but I'm not clear on how to identify this. As far as I can tell each program is sleeping between poll intervals, and the intervals are not high (one query per minute). We just Traced SQL for an hour, and there were only in the region of 700 updates, but still tens of gigabytes of transaction log.

Does anybody have an idea how to debug the transaction log? - I'd like to see what's being recorded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main driver of high transaction log data is not the number of SQL commands executed but the size/number of records affected by those commands.

In addition to DML commands (DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE) also DDL commands like CREATE and ALTER table produce redo log data. For example, re-partitioning a large table will produce a large volume of redo logs.

For HANA there are tools (`hdblogdiag`) that allow inspecting the log volume structures. However, the usage and output of this (and similar tools) absolutely require extensive knowledge of the internals of how HANA operates redo logs.

For the OPs situation, I recommend checking for the volume of data changes caused by both DML and DDL.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue.

There is a bug in SAP HANA SPS11 < 112.06 and SPS12 < 122.02 in the LOB garbage collector for the row store.

You can take a look at the [SAP Note 2351467](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2351467)

In short, you can either

- upgrade HANA
- or convert the rowstore tables containing LOB columns into columnstore with the query ALTER TABLE "<schema_name>"."<table_name>" COLUMN;

You can find the list with this query :

```
select
distinct lo.schema_name,
lo.table_name
from sys.m_table_lob_files lo
inner join tables ta on lo.table_oid = ta.table_oid
and ta.table_type = 'ROW'
```

- or disable the row store lob garbage collector by editing the indexserver.ini to set "garbage_lob_file_handler_enabled = false" under the [row_engine] section.

Comment: HANA 1 is out of support by now; if this really is a bug the OP hits, upgrading would be the best way forward.

Comment: You are right @LarsBr. 

But upgrade from HANA 1 to HANA 2 is not so easy... specifically with SAP B1.
- HANA 1 is used by SAP Business One 9.x ; so if you want upgrade to HANA 2 you have to upgrade SAP Business One to 10.x
- SAP Business One 10.x is only 64 bits. So if you have add-ons only in 32bits, they cannot run.
- If your add-on are 64 bits, you can still have problem with HANA 2 because of the change of connection (single tenant on 30015 vs multi-tenant on 30013) and because some UPDATE query are no longer working.

Comment: btw, you can still upgrade HANA 1.0 SPS11 or HANA 1.0 SPS12 to another revision of HANA 1.0 SPS11 and SPS12.

Comment: The system is HANA Plat. Edtn 2 - It's in place to run a SAP Business One installation, so I don't think that it's appropriate to change the storage engine.